# how do I compare my data-type which might be either a Rational or Float

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

given that I have a data type of:

```
data Number = Float Float | Rational Integer Integer
```

why wouldn't this code works?

```
createComparator :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> Number -> Number -> Bool
createComparator comparator (Float f1) (Float f2) = comparator f1 f2
createComparator comparator (Float f) (Rational n d) = comparator f $ (fromIntegral n) / (fromIntegral d)
createComparator comparator (Rational n d) (Float f) = comparator ((fromIntegral n) / (fromIntegral d)) f
-- createComparator comparator (Rational n1 d1) (Rational n2 d2) = ... -- TODO
```

so, it basically take a comparator (>) or (<), and 2 Number, and return Bool.

e.g: 0.5 > 1/3 == True

or, 0.2 > 1/3 == False

but, I get this error.

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Float’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        createComparator :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> Number -> Number -> Bool
      at Ramadoka/Parser/Number.hs:55:23
Relevant bindings include
  comparator :: a -> a -> Bool
    (bound at Ramadoka/Parser/Number.hs:56:20)
  createComparator :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> Number -> Number -> Bool
    (bound at Ramadoka/Parser/Number.hs:56:3)
In the first argument of ‘comparator’, namely ‘f1’
In the expression: comparator f1 f2
```

I could make it works by doing:

```
(|>|) :: Number -> Number -> Bool
(Float f1) |>| (Float f2) = f1 > f2
(Float f) |>| (Rational n d) = f > (fromIntegral n) / (fromIntegral d)
(Rational n d) |>| (Float f) = (fromIntegral n) / (fromIntegral d) > f
r1@(Rational _ _) |>| r2@(Rational _ _) = rationalCompare r1 r2 == GT

(|<|) :: Number -> Number -> Bool
(Float f1) |<| (Float f2) = f1 < f2
(Float f) |<| (Rational n d) = f < (fromIntegral n) / (fromIntegral d)
(Rational n d) |<| (Float f) = (fromIntegral n) / (fromIntegral d) < f
r1@(Rational _ _) |<| r2@(Rational _ _) = rationalCompare r1 r2 == LT
```

though, I'd  still prefer to have:

```
(|>|) = createComparator (>)
(|<|) = createComparator (<)
```

Comment: I think you're overthinking it. If you write `instance Ord Number where compare (Float f1) (Float f2) = compare f1 f2; compare ..` then you get the desired `<` and `>` functions for free (from the default definitions in `Ord`). No higher order functions (let alone higher rank types) required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caveat: I do not have a Haskell compiler handy, so I can't check my work

The short answer is to just change the `a` to `Float`.

Let's play along though and see what happens. What your type signature is telling me is if I provide a function `a -> a -> Bool` for any possible `a`, your function will work. Even if I give you some ridiculous function such as `String -> String -> Bool` your function will do its job. Note that for any polymorphic `a` there is an implicit `forall` that Haskell hides on the left of your type signature.

"For any `a` you choose, you can give me an `a -> a -> Bool` and I'll give you a `Number -> Number -> Bool`."

```
forall a. (a -> a -> Bool) -> Number -> Number -> Bool
```

That's not what you want to say though presumably. You want your comparator to be of type `Float -> Float -> Bool` since you're converting your own personal `Rational` into a `Float`.

If you want to figure out how to get the polymorphism you originally desired,  what you're looking for is [higher rank types](https://wiki.haskell.org/Rank-N_types).

So before we start this journey, enable rank-n types with this at the top of your file.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
```

You probably want to say something closer to the following, which involves moving the `forall` into a set of parentheses.

"If you give me a function such that for any chosen type `a`, I can compare the two and give you a `Bool`, then I can give you a `Number -> Number -> Bool`."

```
(forall a. a -> a -> Bool) -> Number -> Number -> Bool
```

Moving your `forall` into one layer of parentheses is what is known as a rank-2 type. If you nest another layer you get rank-3 and so on.

This still isn't what you want because the type constraint is too powerful. `forall a. a -> a -> Bool` must be constantly true or false to work for all possible `a`. What you probably want is a typeclass constraint to narrow down the `a` you care about.

```
(forall a. Ord a => a -> a -> Bool) -> Number -> Number -> Bool
```

In your particular case, even this is basically overkill and you could just go with `Float` as mentioned earlier, because that's ultimately what `forall a. Ord a => a -> a -> Bool` will specialize to.

And if you have that as your signature, I think you're done (don't have a Haskell compiler handy right now).

Comment: Yes, making the type - signature to be Float -> Float -> Bool could works, and it'd also probably works for comparing Rational, if I compare the Float version of my Rational, e.g: 1/5 as 0.2. Though, it's not exactly what I intend to do. Your solution works really well though, thank you.

Comment: @Ramadoka, what are you intending to do out of curiosity? Compare `Rational` and `Float` directly without any need for conversion of either?

Comment: Sorry, I mean if I'm comparing between a Rational against another Rational,  I don't want them to be first converted to Float. e.g: 3/25 > 1/5  = False. I don't really know the behavior of converting Integer to Float, like for example if I have a = 1/3129292 and b = 99/312929200, I don't think it's really safe, to assume a > b is always correct.

Comment: In that case the polymorphic signature that both I and @DanielWagner suggested will get you that. When comparing a `Float` and a `Rational` though, you're still going to need to convert them to a common type before doing the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Turn on `Rank2Types` and write the type of the function this way:

```
createComparator :: (forall a. Ord a => a -> a -> Bool) -> Number -> Number -> Bool
```

As you wrote it, there is a particular type `a` for which you are passing in a comparator; whereas you want to pass in a function which is polymorphically a comparator for many types (hence must mention `forall` in its type).